# How do I add google sign in on Appwrite without client id

Tags: android, google-signin, appwrite

I am building an application that requires log in and sign up. I am using Appwrite for backend and want a "sign in with google" button in it. I went to the google developer console and created a project, added credentials and everything. It provided me with a JSON file and a client ID. I went to appwrite to add the google as an authentication client but it is asking for a "client secret". I did some research and it seems like google developer console no longer provides you with a "client secret". What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you're selecting "Web application" for the Application type because the OAuth flow is between Google and the Appwrite backend and not Google and your mobile app.

For more info, see https://dev.to/appwrite/appwrite-flutter-implementing-oauth-login-aem#configure-google-sign-in.